# Golang Clone github repository in memory and run shell script that will create files in same repository

Tags: shell, go

I have following code for cloning github repo,

```
var store *memory.Storage
var fs billy.Filesystem

func cloneRepo(Repo string) *git.Repository {
store = memory.NewStorage()
fs = memfs.New()

r, err := git.Clone(store, fs, &git.CloneOptions{
    URL:           Repo,
    Auth:          getAuth(),
    ReferenceName: plumbing.NewBranchReferenceName("development"),
    SingleBranch:  true,
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("%v", err)
}

fmt.Println("Repository cloned")
```

I have a shell script file in the cloned repo when it runs it creates some file. Is there any possibility that I can run shell script with above implementation( in memory cloned repo).Since I do not want to clone repo locally and do that.

Comment: If you want to run a script, which creates files, then said script would need to have access to the same filesystem (ie the same memory). Looking at the [capability constants](https://github.com/go-git/go-billy/blob/v5.3.1/fs.go#L20), executable isn't supported, which honestly is a relief. Supporting arbitrary code execution is one hell of an attack vector

Comment: That means this is not possible with current implementation(memory and billy). Any idea how can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can't do what you're describing. It is technically impossible.

Comment: @nautilus: The way to run a script after cloning a repo is by doing what you say you want to avoid: clone it to disk, make the file executable, and execute it. That's assuming you trust the script, of course.

Comment: If the shell script interacts with the repo's contents, you need to put those contents on a filesystem that exists outside of the go process, so the shell script's interpreter can access.  If the shell script doesn't need to interact with the repo's contents, you can pipe the shell script to its interpreter's standard input, then you don't need to put the shell script somewhere the interpreter can access.